# how i can monitor gpu sensors?

Tags: c#, gpu, hardware

im using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware dll for tracking the gpu sensors , but im not getting fan speed . please help it .

```cs
private void Get_GPU_Configuration()
{
    try
    {
        Computer _comp = new Computer();
        _comp.GPUEnabled = true;
        _comp.Open();
        dgv_Main_Window.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (var hardwareItem in _comp.Hardware)
        {
            if ((hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuAti) || (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia))
            {
                int index = dgv_Main_Window.Rows.Add();
                string _device_Name = hardwareItem.Name.Trim();// Radeon(TM) R5 M430
                hardwareItem.Update();
                dgv_Main_Window.Rows[index].Cells[int_Device].Value = _device_Name;
                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    string str = sensor.SensorType.ToString();
                    if (str == "Temperature")
                    {
                        dgv_Main_Window.Rows[index].Cells[int_Temperature].Value = sensor.Value.ToString();
                    }
                    if (str == "Clock")
                    {
                        if (sensor.Name == "GPU Core")
                        {
                            dgv_Main_Window.Rows[index].Cells[int_CoreClock].Value = sensor.Value.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dgv_Main_Window.Rows[index].Cells[int_MemoryClock].Value = sensor.Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    if (str == "Fan")
                    {
                        if (sensor.Name == "GPU Fan")
                        {
                            dgv_Main_Window.Rows[index].Cells[int_FanSpeed].Value = sensor.Value;
                        }

                    }



                }


                string[] _deviceName_Array = new string[dgv_Main_Window.Rows.Count];
                foreach (DataGridViewRow _drow in dgv_Main_Window.Rows)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    _deviceName_Array[i] = _drow.Cells[int_Device].Value.ToString();
                    i++;
                }

                ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(@"root\cimv2");
                ObjectQuery oq2 = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_VideoController");
                ManagementObjectSearcher _Video = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, oq2);

                foreach (ManagementObject obj in _Video.Get())
                {
                    foreach (PropertyData PC in obj.Properties)
                    {

                    }

                    foreach (var _data in _deviceName_Array)
                    {
                        if (_data == obj["Name"].ToString())
                        {
                            foreach (DataGridViewRow _drow in dgv_Main_Window.Rows)
                            {
                                if (_drow.Cells[int_Device].Value.ToString() == _data)
                                {
                                    _drow.Cells[int_Id].Value = obj["DeviceID"].ToString();
                                    _drow.Cells[int_Driver].Value = obj["DriverVersion"].ToString();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }


}
```

Comment: be more specific. what errors are you getting?

Comment: Guys go easy, OP is new.

Answer (score -1):

A quick google and I found the code:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature"); 
foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get()) 
{ 
   MessageBox.Show(((Convert.ToInt32(mo["CurrentTemperature"]) - 2732) / 10).ToString()); 
} 

ManagementObjectSearcher mos1 = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\cimv2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Fan"); 
foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos1.Get()) 
{ 
   MessageBox.Show(mo["DesiredSpeed "].ToString()); 
}
```

The problem is MoBo manufacturers sometimes don't give out the info. If it doesn't work with this or your solution check the specs of the Motherboard.

Comment: i need to find  gpu sensor details  like fan speed , temp, etc

Comment: That's what my post answers. It shows you how to get the current temp and 'desired' fan speed. There are dozens of other readings you can get but some Manufacturers provide slightly different MoBo features, particularly in the gaming industry/market.